# Making a border around text with background image without affecting image

Tags: css, background, background-image, border

I have a background image with a h1 and paragraph tag on top. I wish to create a border around the h1 tag without affecting the padding or margin of the header. When I create the border, it surrounds the text **and** the top padding. Is there a way to apply a border around the text only?

The complete code is on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/NouranS96/9ss2g8eL/).

The CSS code is here:

```
header {
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/8263/pexels-
photo.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-top: 180px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?
[image: border around h1]

Below is the code that was used to get the effect. You can have a play with the padding and margins for the H1 to space it out if you want.

```css
body{
 background-color: #404040;
}

header{
 background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/8263/pexels-photo.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
 height: 500px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 padding-top: 180px;
 text-align:center;
}
h1{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
 padding:0px;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 auto;
 line-height:40px;
}
p{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <h1>Guitar Covers</h1>
   <p>This is a new page for uploading my Guitar Covers to share with the world</p>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much that's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I went a different rout and created a wrapper around the `H1` with the `padding-top`

https://jsfiddle.net/9ss2g8eL/1/

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="h1_surround">

  <h1>Guitar Covers</h1>
  </div>
        <p>This is a new page for uploading my Guitar Covers to share with the world</p>
    </header>
</body>



body{
    background-color: #404040;
}

header{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/8263/pexels-photo.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
#h1_surround{
  padding-top:180px;
}
h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: auto;
  border:1px solid #FF0000;
  width:350px;
}
p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: This is also a great solution. I guess the only way to do it is by just separating the header declarations from that of the h1. Thank you for your efforts.